# update password in docker-compose without deleting volume

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want to update my mariadb password in my docker-compose without deleting the volume I don't know if it possible
Everytime I update the password in my docker-compose I have to delete the volume and it delete all the data in my database
Here is my docker compose

```
version: '3'

services:
  php:
    build:
      context: ./php   # Le chemin vers le Dockerfile du service PHP
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
    ports:
      - "8080:80"

  mariadb:
    image: mariadb
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    volumes:
      - mariadb-data:/var/lib/mysql

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
    ports:
      - "8181:80"
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: mariadb

volumes:
  mariadb-data:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately i think is not possible just updating the docker-compose file, instead you should connect directly to the instance of the container db and update the password manually following the standard database rules

```bash
docker exec -it {container_id} mysql -u root -p

mysql> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'MyNewPass';
```